# How is bond albedo calculated?

Tags: earth, albedo

According to [this](http://Bond%20albedos%20are%20computed%20by%20calculating%20the%20ratio%20of%20the%20flux%20reflected%20by%20a%20planet%20(integrated%20over%20wavelength)%20to%20the%20total%20stellar%20flux%20incident%20on%20the%20planet.) website, Bond albedos are computed by calculating the ratio of the flux reflected by a planet (integrated over wavelength) to the total stellar flux incident on the planet.

Three questions:

> 1. How to arrive to "the ratio of the flux reflected by" the earth?
> 2. How to arrive to "the total stellar flux incident on" the earth?
> 3. How to compute the two together?

Comment: The Bond albedo is a value strictly between 0 and 1, as it includes all possible scattered light (but not radiation from the body itself).

Comment: “The thermal radiant energy flux incident upon the surface of the earth may be separated into two components. Solar flux that arrives within the 0.3 to 3.5 micrometer wavelength range and the downward longwave radiation flux in the 3.5 to 50 micrometer wavelength range. Since the longwave radiation is invisible and of relatively constant magnitude, it is often neglected. However the relative constant characteristic of the longwave radiation is important to the ecosystems receiving it, as the total influx of radiation dwarfs other inflows of heat in the energy budget of almost all ecosystems.”

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/energy-flux-incident